# Can you specify format for XmlSerialization of a datetime?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I need to serialize / deserialize a datetime into yyyyMMdd format for an XML file.  Is there an attribute / workaround I can use for this?

Comment: You can manipulate the getter and setter of the variable. For example I had an enum Sex{Unknown, Female, Male} and I had a string setter which formattet m into male and f into female. The xml serializer also wrote f and m inseatd of the full enum name. Worked fine but there's nearly no practical usage for this.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

No, there isn't. If it's in that format, then it's not a valid dateTime as far as XML Schema is concerned.

The best you can do is as follows:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public DateTime DoNotSerialize {get;set;}

public string ProxyDateTime {
    get {return DoNotSerialize.ToString("yyyyMMdd");}
    set {DoNotSerialize = DateTime.Parse(value);}
}
```

Comment: Worth noting: both a get/set must be present. I spent a half hour debugging why my property wasn't being serialized. It turns out I had no 'set', because I thought to myself, 'I'll never be changing this value; why bother writing a set?'

Comment: @spamguy: XmlSerializer only handles public properties with both a public get and public set.

Answer (score 22):

[XmlElementAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx)#DataType should provide what you need:

```
[XmlElement(DataType="date")]    
public DateTime Date1 {get;set;}
```

This will get *Date1* property serialized to the proper [xml date](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-2-20010502/#date) format.

Comment: No, the problem is that I needed to serialize it to a non-standard xml date format.  The accepted solution is what I went for.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, gives a build error. [XmlElement(DataType="date")] works.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed my problem. I was trying to remove the Time component. Cheers!

Comment: Works great if you need YYYY-MM-DD, which I actually need DD/MM/YYYY, Doh!