# Set String value as that propreties type/ XML Deserialize to class. C#

Tags: c#, xml

Sorry if the name of the thread is unclear. I had no idea how to form it properly. Anyways.

I have a class.

```
Class Overflow {
public string Name;
public decimal MoneySpent;
public string Code;
}
```

Then I have an XML that has value

```
<Data>
    <Name>John</LeidimoNr>
    <MoneySpent>78621.25</Code>
    <Code>XA-21456-sds</Code>
</Data>
```

So I need to put all of the XML values into the object Overflow.

What I'm doing is I'm iterating through Data

```
   foreach (XPathNavigator val in it)
   {
       var name = val.Name;
       var value = val.Value;
       var Type = Overflow.GetType();
       PropertyInfo info = Type.GetProperty(name);
       info.SetValue(Overflow, value, null);
   }
```

But the value is set to string and there's one value Decimal.

How do I make PropertyType same as in my class?

Comment: Related Thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330155/c-sharp-xml-serialization-and-decimal-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do the trick

```
info.SetValue(Overflow, Convert.ChangeType(value, Type.PropertyType), null);
```

[Convert.ChangeType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130977(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation

Answer (score 2):

Instead of re-inventing the wheel, why not use the built-in `XmlSerializer` to do this?

Add the relevant attributes to your class, and make your fields properties:

```
[XmlRoot("Data")]
public class Overflow
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public decimal MoneySpent { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a serializer and pass it the XML source:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Overflow));
var obj = (Overflow) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eqVbZI) for a working demo.

Comment: Well the problem with this solution was that I'm using DeserializeReply(message, object[] parameters) and it doesn't have the normal "XML" and I don't nkow how to turn that "message" that I'm given into reader. Only figured it out with var doc = new XPathDocument(message.GetReaderAtBodyContents());

Comment: @Wkjjjj `GetReaderAtBodyContents` returns an `XmlReader`.  You can pass that to `serializer.Deserialize`.

Comment: "There is an error in XML document (1, 620)." {"<Response xmlns='MyWebServiceAdress'> was not expected."}

Somehow it spits an error.

Comment: Then your message body and your class don't match - it evidently starts with `Response` rather than `Overflow`, so you'd need to have a class that matched the entirety of the response.  I'm sure generally there must be built-in ways to solve this issue, but I'm not familiar enough with WCF to advise..

Comment: Well. The whole problem is that the people I'm dealing with can't fix their WSDL and I have to Serialize everything like I didin't have an WSDL. There's loads of different WebService calls and I have to catch them all. It's really a hassle to explain so much so I'll just suck it up and manually code the putting to objects.