# Serialize DateTime property to XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, datetime, serialization

I´m a programming student and I would like to know if it is possible to change the format of a date when I serialize it in a xml file. This date is an attribute of an ObservableCollection of objects "Loan", this objects have two DateTime properties, one of the dates is a nullable object. I serialize all the collection including the date.

I would like to obtain in the xml file:

```
<OutDate> 15-03-2014 </OutDate>
<!--If the date is null I don´t want to appear the node-->
```

And I´m getting this:

```
 <OutDate>2014-03-15T00:00:00</OutDate>
 <InDate xsi:nil="true" />
```

This is part of my code project:
Part of my class Loan, already mark as serializable, looks like this:

```
    private string isbn;
    private string dni;
    private DateTime dateOut;
    private DateTime? dateIn;    
    // Setters and Gettters and constructors
```

This is the method for serialize:

```
// I will pass three collections to this method loans, books and clients
public void SerializeToXML<T>(string file, string node, ObservableCollection<T> collection)
        {
            XmlRootAttribute root = new XmlRootAttribute(node);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<T>), root);
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(fs, collection);
            }
        }
```

The call:

```
SerializeToXML<Loan>(_file, "Library", manager.LoansCollection);
```

Thnks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to achieve this is to implement the [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface on your class instead. Something along the following lines

```
public class Loan : IXmlSerializable
{
    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        if(dateIn.HasValue)
        {
            writer.WriteElementString("dateIn", dateIn.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

On the read you'll need to read the Element name, if it's dateIn set that, otherwise set the appropriate value. Basically checking to see if it exists in the XML.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to implement [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), some DateTime to string conversion of a backing field should do the trick, something like this:

```
    public class Loan
    {
        [XmlIgnore]
        private DateTime _dateOut;

        public string OutDate
        {
            get { return _dateOut.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"); }
            set { _dateOut = DateTime.Parse(value); }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the XmlElement attribute class (in System.Xml.Serialization). If that doesn't work then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118833/can-you-specify-format-for-xmlserialization-of-a-datetime) shows  how to use a proxy property

```
[XmlElement("TheDate", DataType = "date")]
    public DateTime TheDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late to get my answer marked as "the one", but you can have control over serialization without implementing complex interfaces or wrapping stuff as a workaround.

```
public DateTime? InDate { get; set }

public bool ShouldSerializeInDate()
{
    return InDate.HasValue;
}
```

The C# XML Serializer has a not so well documented functionality. Every public property can have a method for turning on or off the serialization of the property. The method has to be called: **ShouldSerializeXYZ** where *XYZ* is the exact name of the property that you want to control.

See:
[Xml serialization - Hide null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818513/xml-serialization-hide-null-values)