# Controlling DateTime format for XML responses in Web API

Tags: .net, datetime, serialization, asp.net-web-api, xml-serialization

How can I control `DateTime` output format when content is requested as `application/xml`? The following works for JSON:

```
 JsonMediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
 jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
     DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd" };
```

What's the equivalent for `XmlMediaTypeFormatter` ?

**Update**:
Semantically, my data have no time information. Technically, I want to a) minimize payload b) simplify consumption (no need to process/format on client side) c) consistent responses regardless of format asked.

Comment: What are you trying to change it to, and why? XML already has a well-defined format for dates and times (ISO-8601) - you should stick with that. Don't forget this is meant to be *machine-readable*, not aimed at end users. (Likewise the JSON - I'd strongly discourage the use of `MM/dd/yyyy` in JSON.)

Comment: Unfortunately the underlaying DB stores dates using datetime datatype. C# does not have date only type as well, right? And my front-end needs date parts only.

Comment: Why does that mean you'd need to use a non-standard format in your XML? That's a non-sequitur, IMO. (As an aside, you might want to check out my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project for a greater variety of date/time types, including "just date" - but that won't change whether or not it's a good idea to use a US-centric date format in XML...)

Comment: Sorry if I made myself unclear. My point is not to use US date format. The point is to omit time parts of C# `DateTime` type in responses. I made it for JSON and want same result in XML for consistensy.

Comment: Right, so are you going to use `yyyy-MM-dd`? Your example of code to force JSON to use a US-centric format is confusing the matter. I suspect there may be an XML serialization attribute to say specifically "this is just a date" at which point you don't need to specify a format...

Comment: I suspect you want to follow the *second* answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118833, i.e. specify `[XmlElement(DataType=date)]`

Comment: That's it! It does work if I set `config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer` to `true`. Can you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't specify your own format - you should instead tell the XML serializer that the value is just meant to be a date, using:

```
[XmlElement(DataType="date")]
```

Then force the use of XML serializer with `config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true` and you should be fine. That way you'll be using the standard (ISO-8601) format for dates, which is `yyyy-MM-dd`... which means standard tools (e.g. LINQ to XML) will be able to parse the XML appropriately.