# RestSharp - XmlSerializer not using the DateFormat property

Tags: c#, datetime, xml-serialization, restsharp, date-formatting

I encountered a problem with the RestSharp library. Defaultly, it serializes DateTime objects using the format `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`. That doesn't work well with my WCF service that only seems to accept `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`, so I tried to alter the serialization of a request with `request.DateFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`.

This property , even though set correctly, seems to be having zero impact on the serialization. At least when using the default `RestSharp.Serializers.XmlSerializer`. If I tried using the `DotNetXmlSerializer`, the DateFormat was working, but then the serializer didn't include my XMLNS link and added version & encoding line to the xml output, one or both of which wasn't compatible with the WCF service either.

Does anybody have any suggestions what am I doing wrong with the `XmlSerializer` ?

Here is the concerned codeblock:

```
var req = new RestRequest(endpoint, Method.POST);
req.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;
//req.XmlSerializer = new DotNetXmlSerializer();
req.XmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer();
req.DateFormat = DATE_FORMAT;
req.AddBody(model, XMLNS);
```

Where `private const string DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"` and `XMLNS` is the URL used in the WCF requests (taken from the endpoint /help documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [`RestRequest.DateFormat`](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/RestRequest.cs) is only used when *deserializing*:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Used by the default deserializers to explicitly set which date format string to use when parsing dates.
    /// </summary>
    public string DateFormat { get; set; }
```

For serializing you need to set it explicitly on the [serializer](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/Serializers/ISerializer.cs):

```
    req.XmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer { DateFormat = DATE_FORMAT };
```

Note that, for [`DotNetXmlSerializer`](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/Serializers/DotNetXmlSerializer.cs), the underlying [`System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not support custom DateTime formats, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118833/can-you-specify-format-for-xmlserialization-of-a-datetime).