# C# deserialize datetime from xml

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I have to deserialize xml with date looking like this:

```
<date>2015/10/16 00:00:00.000000000</date>
```

My class contains this field:

```
[XmlAttribute("date")]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

But I always receive default date. Is it possible to parse this format of datetime?

Edit:
When I change XmlAttribute to XmlElement, I get exception:

```
There is an error in XML document
```

So I think DateTime can's parse this format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force XmlSerializer to serialize DateTime as 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534525/force-xmlserializer-to-serialize-datetime-as-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss)

Comment: And also [Can you specify format for XmlSerialization of a datetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118833/can-you-specify-format-for-xmlserialization-of-a-datetime).  `[XmlElement]` is the correct annotation to use, you get the default `DateTime` value with `[XmlAttribute("date")]` because the element value is being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this is to decorate the DateTime member with
    **[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]**

This tells the serializer to not serialize or de-serialize it at all.

Then, add an additional property to the class, called, for example DateString.  It might be defined as

```
public string DateString {
    set { ... }
    get { ... }
}
```

Then you can serialize and de-ser the DateString in the get/set  logic:

```
public string DateString {
    set {
    // parse value here - de-ser from your chosen format
    // use constructor, eg, Timestamp= new System.DateTime(....);
    // or use one of the static Parse() overloads of System.DateTime()
    }
    get {
        return Timestamp.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd");  // serialize to whatever format you want.
    }
}
```

Within the get and set you are manipulating the value of the Date member, but you are doing it with custom logic.   The serialized property need not be a string of course, but that is a simple way to do it.     You could also ser/de-ser using an int, as with the unix epoch, for example

by Dino Chiesa