# WCF 4.5 contract-first not generating simple types "correctly"

Tags: .net, wcf, xsd, .net-4.5, contract-first

I have the following simple type defined in an XSD:

```
    <xs:simpleType name="TimeOfDay">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">The representation of a time value that does not include time zone/offset information.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:time">
        <xs:minInclusive value="00:00:00"/>
        <xs:pattern value="(([01][0-9])|(2[0-3]))(:[0-5][0-9]){2}(\.[0-9]+)?"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

When I generate the C# code from this using the WCF code-gen feature in .NET 4.5, it maps this type to DateTime.  As a result, when we serialize the data contract to XML, the value fails schema validation because it contains the full date/time value, "dd-mm-yyyyThh:mm:ss.fff".

Any idea how we can either:

1. Have the generated code implement the necessary restrictions
2. Customize the serialization process so only the time component of
   the value is written into the XML output

Comment: time data type is not supported in .net, it will use DateTime. If you need to return the time part only, you will need to change it to string or use XmlSerialization to change format. Here there's also a implementation that can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118833/can-you-specify-format-for-xmlserialization-of-a-datetime

Comment: Because the WCF code-gen doesn't actually generate class files and only generates the types in the dll, there is no opportunity to extend the class or annotate the properties as described in that post.

Comment: You can generate the class using xsd tool, put the attributes and compile the class. Or, if you really want to use code gem, you will need to change the data type to string.

Comment: If you are referring to WSCF.blue as the "xsd tool", then we cannot.  We have a complicated schema structure spread across multiple files and namespaces and we've already found the WSCF.blue can't handle it.  We are using the built-in code-gen feature in WCF 4.5.

Comment: Yes, you are right abou xsd tool, I had problems too. I use svcutil.exe instead, it works fine to generate classes. When using complex schemas with multiple file, the references must be ok across the all files. Just trying to give you some more alternatives.

Comment: svcutil, as I understand it, does not support XML attributes.  We have a ton of those in the XSDs.