# C# 10 XmlSerializer Deserialize DateOnly / DateTime to specific format

Tags: c#, deserialization, datetime-format, xmlserializer

How to use `XmlSerializer` to `Deserialize` to specific `DateOnly` and `DateTime` format? I receive `<ShipDate>31.10.2022</ShipDate>` from and XML API endpoint and it deserializes to `1/1/0001`

Comment: As far as I know, `XmlSerializer` still doesn't support custom DateTime formats.  The workaround is still to use a string surrogate property as shown in [Can you specify format for XmlSerialization of a datetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1118833) and [Force XmlSerializer to serialize DateTime as 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3534525).  If you want the standard DateOnly xml format, use `[XmlElement(DataType="date")]` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5025905) by [th2tran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142303/th2tran).

Comment: Date/time types in .NET _have no inherent format._  That won't occur until you use say `.ToString()` at which point you can specify a format.

Comment: Dotnet runtime github issue for this: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/56711