# XMLSerializer serializing DateTime property with timezone

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have an object with `DateTime` properties. The values do not include the timezone. The `Kind` property is `Local`. I then serialize the object as follows:

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings()
{
    Indent = true,
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true
};

using (var sw = new StringWriter())
using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw, settings))
{
    serializer.Serializer.Serialize(xw, myObj);
    myXml = sw.ToString();
}
```

The string is serialized and the value of the value of the date properties has been modified during serialization and now the time part has the time zone added/subtracted to it.

My first question is: Does the serializer use the system settings to serialize datetime properties?

And my actual question is: Is there a way to make the serializer ignore the timezone (preferably setting some property on the serializer and not modifying objects)?

Comment: There is no way to customize XmlSerializer's DateTime format, see [Can you specify format for XmlSerialization of a datetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1118833) and [Force XmlSerializer to serialize DateTime as 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3534525).  In both those questions the suggested workaround is to use a surrogate property.